# Delete Item on DynamoDB CLI localhost

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoDB's Table called "ZombieSession" and the "SessionId" primary key with "S" type.

The local service is running in http://localhost:8181.

For local tests, I'm trying execute these commands:

**(1)**

> aws dynamodb delete-item --table-name ZombieSession --key
>   '4ae40a08-007c-4785-babd-caff0ed12d1d' --endpoint-url
>   http://localhost:8181 --region us-east-1

That results in:

> Error parsing parameter '--key': Invalid JSON:
>   '4ae40a08-007c-4785-babd-caff0ed12d1d'

and

**(2)**

> aws dynamodb delete-item --table-name ZombieSession --key
>   '{"SessionId":{"S":"4ae40a08-007c-4785-babd-caff0ed12d1d"}}'
>   --endpoint-url http://localhost:8181 --region us-east-1

That results in:

> Error parsing parameter '--key': Invalid JSON:
>   '{SessionId:{S:4ae40a08-007c-4785-babd-caff0ed12d1d}}'

I don't found any documentation example about this.

What's the appropriate command for this operation?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I discovered that the value of --key parameter need have the quotation mark with escape:

> aws dynamodb delete-item --table-name ZombieSession --key
>   "{\"SessionId\":{\"S\":\"4ae40a08-007c-4785-babd-caff0ed12d1d\"}}"
>   --endpoint-url http://localhost:8181 --region us-east-1

Comment: Thanks! It's weird that that is not mentioned anywhere in `aws` command line help.

Comment: Might be because that's part of shell syntax, it's how a double quote is escaped inside double quotes.

Comment: `aws-shell` helps

Comment: i used delete-table instead of delete-item but your answer still helped me